# Why doesn't it console.log() anything if I copy and paste it?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have this code run on [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) to add \n before dialogue, if I type something into the space where words are in toFormat it works fine but if I copy and paste something into it, it doesn't console.log anything

```js
/* !!! */
let toformat = `
“Excuse me,” he said. The young woman didn’t respond. “What are you doing?” “Hey, I’m talking to you” Rudy said.
`
/* !!! */

let truef = false

/* !!! */
let run = true

/* !!! */

if(run){

  let res = []

  let dialogue = []
  let other = []
  let split = toformat.split('"').join('|"').split('|').slice(1)

  split.forEach((x, i) => {
    if(i % 2 == 1){
      other.push(x)
    } else {
      dialogue.push(x)
    }
  })



  for(let i = 0; i < dialogue.length; i++){
    res.push('\n' + dialogue[i] + '"')
    res.push(other[i].slice(1))
  }

  console.log(res.join(''))
  console.log(Math.random())

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to copy and paste?  Where are you trying to paste it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to split on `"` but the string contains `“` which is a different ASCII character. Common copy + paste problem.

Changing the characters in toformat works:

```
/* !!! */
let toformat = `
"Excuse me," he said. The young woman didn't respond. "What are you doing?" "Hey, I’m talking to you" Rudy said.
`
/* !!! */

let truef = false

/* !!! */
let run = true

/* !!! */

if(run){

  let res = []

  let dialogue = []
  let other = []
  let split = toformat.split('"').join('|"').split('|').slice(1)

  split.forEach((x, i) => {
    if(i % 2 == 1){
      other.push(x)
    } else {
      dialogue.push(x)
    }
  })



  for(let i = 0; i < dialogue.length; i++){
    res.push('\n' + dialogue[i] + '"')
    res.push(other[i].slice(1))
  }

  console.log(res.join(''))
  console.log(Math.random())

}
```

result:

```
"Excuse me," he said. The young woman didn't respond. 
"What are you doing?" 
"Hey, I’m talking to you" Rudy said.
```